# Podio Scrum Board

Tags: scrum, podio

Does anyone know how to get the board, like in the picture?

https://podio.com/store/pack/110-demo-scrum-board?return_type=&return_id=46

Regards,

Johnny

Comment: The product doesn't appear to be on that page anymore. What are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podio app in the link doesnt exists any more.
But if you're looking for the Virtual Scrum Board for Podio, the code and instructions can be found on Podio Blog here: https://developers.podio.com/showcase/scrumboard

ScrumIO is great btw, and highly recommended.